# Firebase Admin sends notification to another service account in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I have two routes in nodejs. 
One is like this, one.js

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var topic = "/topics/news";

var serviceAccount = require("/path/serice-1-firebase-adminsdk.json");

var firebase = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://service-1-database.firebaseio.com/"
});

console.log(firebase.name);
```

Then I am sending the notification like this

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  var payload = {
    data: {
      title: req.body.title,
      message: req.body.message
    }
  };
  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(topic, payload)
    .then(function(response) {

      console.log("value of topic ", topic);
      console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });

});
```

And in another route, two.js, I am doing this

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var topic = "/topics/news";
var serviceAccount = require("path/service-2-firebase-adminsdk.json");

var firebase = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://service-2-database.firebaseio.com"
},"other");
console.log(firebase.name);
```

Then again I am sending the notification like this

```
router.post('/notify',function(req,res){
  var category = req.body.category;

      var payload = {
        data: {
          title: "title",
          message: "desc"
        }
      };


      admin.messaging().sendToDevice(topic, payload)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log("value of topic ", topic);
          console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });

});
```

When I try to send the notification using two.js for service-2, the notification gets sent for service-1 but the service account for two is service-2. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`admin.messaging()` always refers to the `messaging` namespace of the default app. In your case default app is the app initialized in `one.js`. So the observed behavior is correct. To send notifications using a custom app, you must do the following:

```
const otherApp = admin.app('other');
admin.messaging(otherApp).sendToDevice(...);
```